# Changing a column type from char to array

Tags: postgresql, alter

I have a table in PostgreSQL that has a `character(1)` column, that I want to change to an `text[]` column, but I can't seem to get it working:

```
ALTER TABLE public.mytable
     ALTER COLUMN abc TYPE TEXT[] COLLATE pg_catalog."default"
     USING ARRAY[abc];
```

gives me this error:

> ERROR:  default for column "abc" cannot be cast automatically to type text[]

which is understandanle, because Postgres can't cast `NULL:bpchar` to an array. But, how can I get this done then? Apparently, `NULL`s can be typed ...

Comment: See [Changing a column from string to string array in postgresql](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14782402/1995738).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to remove the default value, change the data type and re-add the default value.
From the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/sql-altertable.html):

> (…) the USING expression is not applied to the column's default value (if any); (…).
>
> This means that when there is no implicit or assignment cast from old to new type, SET DATA TYPE might fail to convert the default even though a USING clause is supplied. In such cases, drop the default with DROP DEFAULT, perform the ALTER TYPE, and then use SET DEFAULT to add a suitable new default.

and the given example:

```
> When the column has a default expression that won't automatically cast to the 
  new data type:
```

```sql
ALTER TABLE foo
    ALTER COLUMN foo_timestamp DROP DEFAULT,
    ALTER COLUMN foo_timestamp TYPE timestamp with time zone
    USING timestamp with time zone 'epoch' + foo_timestamp * interval '1 second',
    ALTER COLUMN foo_timestamp SET DEFAULT now();
```