# Rails change existing text column to array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

Using the Postgres database, added a text field `staff_ids` to `branches` table:

```
add_column :branches, :staff_ids, :text
```

In controller added this field to branch_params list:

```
:staff_ids => []
```

Data has been saved in this column like `["","32","52"]`. When querying this field I got an error saying staff_ids should be an array

```
Branch.where("? = ANY(staff_ids)", '20')

ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::WrongObjectType: ERROR:  op ANY/ALL (array) requires array on right side
```

Actually, I forgot to add `array: true` option in the migration when adding `staff_ids` field.
Now added another migration to change this column and tried to add `array: true` option:

```
change_column :branches, :staff_ids, :text, array: true
```

But the migration failed with an error:

```
PG::DatatypeMismatch: ERROR:  column "staff_ids" cannot be cast automatically to type text[]
```

Now either I want to update the where clause so that it filters the branches based on staff_ids without adding the array: true or fix the migration mentioned above.

Any suggestion / idea ?

Comment: you can try fixing it with SQL on db level, but you probably want to fix a migration?..

Comment: Want to fix it in a migration in order to execute it on staging and prod environments

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing a column from string to string array in postgresql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14782148/changing-a-column-from-string-to-string-array-in-postgresql)

Comment: You can run the code in that answer in a migration.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the following in your migration,

```
def up
    change_column :branches, :staff_ids, :text, array: true, default: [], using: "(string_to_array(staff_ids, ','))"
end

def down
    change_column :branches, :staff_ids, :text, array: false, default: nil, using: "(array_to_string(staff_ids, ','))"
end
```

Defining up and down methods will help to reverse your migration at any time, if the change to an array was not required.